# Is RANK.EQ calculating wrong?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel's `RANK.EQ` seems to have miscounted.

I have sorted descending the data in the left column (which is Column V on my sheet). Column W, Row 58 has the formula:

```
=RANK.EQ(V58,V$3:V$89)`.
```

Here are Rows 56 to 58 (there are two rows of headers):

```
Sorted descending    `RANK.EQ(V(same row),V$3:V$89)`
    74                   54
    74                   54
    73                   57
```

In the first shown row, the rank is 54. The second one is the "55th", but becomes 54 since it's tied with the previous row. The next row should be ranked 56. What gives?

I think I'm on Version 2004 (but that's not an option in tags), Build 12730.20236.

**EDIT**: Pics added. This is a different tab of the sae spreadsheet.  The first pic shows Column N's formula and shows the column's values skipping 53 .. 51, **52, 54,** ...

[image: Formula shows for Column N]

This one shows my sorting, just for confirmation

[image: Show's Sorting by Column M]

**EDIT 2**: I changed the column to "General" format.

[image: General formatting for column M]

**EDIT 3**: [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1b9NDGWjpQh9OT611VsE6dFPpz_XnxK9i) is a link to a modified file which, hopefully, has stripped out my students' identifying info. It won't be there forever: 
[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zsKrtVQyQa4udiZsL5R-0Co2gJim_Go2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1b9NDGWjpQh9OT611VsE6dFPpz_XnxK9i)

Comment: it is unlikely the formula is doing something wrong, upload an image of your data set to give a full view of the problem

Comment: @PeterH Yes, it really seems strange. I will upload an image as soon as I figure out how (and find the spreadsheet again).

Comment: The data shows the formatted values, not the underlying values, as is apparent from the Rank result. Two values for `57.0` should receive the same rank, hence the underlying data must be different. Could it be that the data also has hidden rows?

Comment: @teylyn Good point. I loaded another pic with it less formatted. But I still see the same issue.

Comment: So, how about hidden rows?

Comment: @Jeff,, better share the WB on clould/Drop box, so we could examine,, seems you are trying to get Unique Rank,,, for data in `col M`!

Comment: @teylyn Not sure what you're getting at. The hidden Cols are calculations to create Col M.Once we have Column M, the rank function should work right, regardless of the hidden columns. Some of the hidden columns aren't even used. At any rate, I have added a link to a

Comment: @RajeshS Added a link (very soon).

Comment: I notice that there's an extra Cell for Average which is M90 included in the formula range. I believe the Range should have been M4:M89. As a result it’s counting Average of 63.1 as one more item but since the formula does not extend to cell N90 it’s just not displaying its rank.

Comment: @patkim Oh wow. I'm so embarrassed to have asked such a question. Anyway, that fixed it. I'm also deleting the file (and request you do the same, just in case it can be used to find out who I and my students are). Also, if you write this as an answer I'll mark it solved.

Comment: @Jeff - Be assured that I have securely deleted the file that I downloaded with 7 random passes.

Comment: @Jeff I never said columns. I said hidden rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since incidentally I happen to notice this question and coincidentally just  happen to be online and could access the file uploaded by @Jeff, I am just posting an answer. Also, to respect the privacy and confidentiality of user’s data, I will just simulate or recreate the issue with a small sample dataset.

While I am posting an answer, I must mention that users @PeterH & @teylyn were absolutely right in their initial assessment of what might be happening here as per their initial comments.

In a nutshell, Range for RANK.EQ was including one extra cell at the end of the data which was not to be included. Below screenshot should be self explanatory.

[image]